# redirect the output of {time}

Tags: stdout, stderr

I am trying to benchmark a single request agains a webserver, and am having a problem doing so, specifically, I am having an issue redirecting the output of the `time` command.

If i simply run

```
time curl "http://www.google.com"
```

my result is the full body response, followed by the printout from the `time` command.

If i run it with redirection

```
time curl "http://www.google.com" 1> out.log 2> err.log
```

In `out.log` I still see the body of the response, and in `err.log` I see the output from the curl command

The problem however is that the output from the `time` command is still printing to the terminal

```
[501] ~ > time curl "http://www.google.com" 1> out.log 2> err.log

real    0m0.092s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.004s

[502] ~ > cat err.log
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 19093    0 19093    0     0   225k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  227k
```

To what buffer does `time` output, and how canI get this into a file? From my understanding, it should have been piped into `err.log`.

Comment: Here is a great way to achieve what you want without the use of time:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215389/how-do-i-measure-request-and-response-times-at-once-using-curl

Comment: ooohhhh, I like that :) and will definitely switch to that as it gives me a lot of the information that i actually need. Still doesn't answer the question though :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try with
`{ time curl -s https://www.google.com ; } > body.txt 2> time.txt`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the bash-internal version but the GNU tool (e.g. `/usr/bin/time`), you have the `-o` option as explained by `man time`:

```
/usr/bin/time -po outfile.txt curl "http://www.google.com"
```

will write the time to `outfile.txt`.

GNU time has many  options to format the output, see the man page for details.

Comment: sure, I can do this, but why will the redirects not work, even `&>` still results in output to the shell.

Comment: Nope, it does not. I just edited my question, showing the output of err.log.

Comment: Correct, I misinterpreted some fragments in the file. Anyway, my guess is that this is due to the fact that this bash-internal isn't really affected by stream redirections, as no process is executed. See Kelzier's variant to avoid this.